# Laravel 5 firstOrCreate keep create even set unique to the field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, laravel-5

Below is my app\Cart.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Cart extends Model {
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'cart';
    protected $fillable = ['sess','uid'];
}
```

Below is my app\Http\Controllers\CartController.php

```
public function cart($id=0, $act, Request $request)
    {
        $sessId = Session::getId();
        switch($act){
            case 'Add':
                $quantity = $request->only('p_quantity');
                $data = $request->except('p_quantity');
                $cartId =  Cart::firstOrCreate(['sess' => $sessId,'status' => 1]);
            break;

            case 'Delete':

            break;
        }

        return response()->json(['success' => true,'message' => 'Success', 'act' => $act, 'id' => $id ,'data' => $data, 'quantity'=> $quantity, 'cart'=>$cartId->id]);
    }
```

What i want is check database if the session key exist in table cart.sess, else create new one and get the id.

Question is , when it keep create new duplicate session to database.

[image: Cart Table]

may i know where i did wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE [2015-05-27 16:02]:**
After i TRUNCATE table and set the sess field to Unique , first submit it look ok, when second submit it show error below:
[image: After change to unique]

**UPDATE [2015-05-27 16:16]**
Code that i use to create database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cart` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sess` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `deleted_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Cause its your own session id it won't change unless your session changes

Comment: @user1578359 can you do the following Cart::whereSess($sessId)->whereStatus(1)->firstOrCreate() and tell us if this works. +shaddy put an arg here, make you 'sess' column unique too.

Answer (score 1):

In your database schema, where you created this cart table, the `sess` column should be unique, but it is not. You should alter it, to be unique:

```
$table->unique('sess');
```

Don't forget to delete all records before that, otherwise you will get an error.

**EDIT** After you posted your table schema I found the problem

```
sess varchar(40) NOT NULL
```

You must set the length of `sess` to at elast 255 characters or the size of your session id, because your session id is longer than 40 symbols. Laravel tries to find a string with 64 characters (or with the length of your session id) for example:

```
8a9f119eaea027def7268d12e4e4d680
```

but did not, so it tries to insert new one. Since your column is with length 40, the sess id got truncated to 40 symbols:

```
8a9f119eaea
```

and in the next check it would not match, because it is searching for `8a9f119eaea027def7268d12e4e4d680` but in your database you got `8a9f119eaea`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but when i change the field to unique, it show duplicate error.  i updated my question.

Comment: @user1578359 Can you post in the question the code that you created this table (the database schema), so I can try to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Hi, @shaddy
I create the database manually using mysql code. Updated to Question.

Comment: I have found the problem, please see my edited answer :)

Comment: Hi @shaddy,
After i TRUNCATE and change the varchar to 255 and also try change to text, problem still exists duplicate error.
or any wrong with my firstOrCreate() function?

Comment: @user1578359 Can you `var_dump(Session::getId())` and then compare the result with this one in DB? Can you post the result and what is in the db?

Comment: Hi @shaddy,
Thanks for your help, after i install laravel debugbar plugin, it help me find the solution. 
Thanks again for your time.
Cheers =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78889/discussion-between-user1578359-and-shaddy).

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem.
**Where**
Because in my modal i using SoftDeletes;
**How To Solved**
it cant has default value inside this field,
but i set it to Default 0000-00-00 00:00:00 , just put it as null by default.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cart` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sess` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

> `deleted_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

```
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

to

> `deleted_at` timestamp

**Why**
firstOrCreate did this query (Check Image Below)
[image]

Plugin Above is : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar for who need it.

Thanks